# How to update website data on digitalocean via SFTP (FileZilla)

Tags: digital-ocean

The customer has a website on digitalcoean. I made a change to the code on my local computer, but I can’t upload it to digitalocean. Help me please!.

I uploaded files to the site via SMTP (FileZilla) but nothing changed.